# When I run complete(), I am getting the an error- Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I have a dataset which looks like this(A-J are column names)

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
1   2   2   3   2   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1
2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1       3   3   3   2   2   2   2
2   1   3   2   2   3   1   1   1   1
    1   3   2   1   2   2   2   1   2
2   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1
2   1   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   1
2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
2   1   1   1           1   1   1   1
2   1   3   3   3   3   1   1   1   2
    1   2   2   1   2   1   1   1   1
    1   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1
2   2   4   1   1   1   2   2   1   1
1   1   3   3   3   3                
2   1   3   3   1   2   2   2   2   3
```

I am getting the below error-

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘complete’ for signature ‘"mids", "numeric"’
```

My data has lot of NULL values and I am trying to impute the data using below code-

```
imp_data<-mice(data = data_NA, m = 5, method = "rf", maxit = 5, seed = 500)
```

I get the error when I run the code-

```
complete(imp_data,1)
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I have added the sample data set after the comments

Comment: no.. That is data_NA

Comment: I know the problem. You got some blank data which is causing problem. Let me add the modified data.

Comment: @MKR Do you mean to say that I have blank data after imputation? How do I remove that?

Comment: if you can share `dput(data_NA)` then may be I can suggest a way to grammatically correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `NA` values are not properly assigned in the `data_NA` data.frame which is causing the problem.

The modified data (with `NA`) and transforming it using `mice` as it worked for me:

```
library(mice)

imp_data <- mice(data = data_NA, m = 5, method = "rf", maxit = 5, seed = 500)
complete(imp_data, 1)
```

**EDITED:** The error seen by OP was resolved by changing the call as:

```
mice::complete(imp_data, 1)
```

May be the `mice::complete` was masked by some function other package.

```
#Result
# A B C D E F G H I J
# 1  1 2 2 3 2 1 1 1 1 2
# 2  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 3  2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1
# 4  2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 5  2 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2 2
# 6  2 1 3 2 2 3 1 1 1 1
# 7  1 3 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 1
# 8  2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1
# 9  1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
# 10 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
# 11 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1
# 12 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
# 13 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 14 2 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 2
# 15 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
# 16 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1
# 17 2 2 4 1 1 1 2 2 1 1
# 18 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 1 2 1
# 19 2 1 3 3 1 2 2 2 2 3
#
```

**Data**

```
data_NA<- read.table(text = 
"A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
1   2   2   3   2   1   1   1   1    NA
2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1
2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1   NA    3   3   3   2   2   2   2
2   1   3   2   2   3   1   1   1   1
1   3   2   1   2   2   2   1   2   NA
2   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   NA
2   1   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   1
2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
2   1   1   1   NA  NA  1   1   1   1
2   1   3   3   3   3   1   1   1   2
1   2   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   NA
1   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   NA
2   2   4   1   1   1   2   2   1   1
1   1   3   3   3   3   NA  NA  NA  NA             
2   1   3   3   1   2   2   2   2   3",header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried doing this and I got the below error-
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘complete’ for signature ‘"mids", "numeric"’

Comment: @DeepaDongarwar I dont see any error mentioned by you? Is there any new error?

Comment: @DeepaDongarwar Call `library(mice)` again and then run it. Or may be call as `mice::complete()`